# json parsing single quotes to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

hava php array something like this:

```
array(1) {
    [39]=>
    array(3) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(21)
            ["name"]=>
            string(14) "32''LE32HDF3010"
        },
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(22)
            ["name"]=>
            string(14) "40''LE40FHDE3010"
        },
        [2]=>
        array(2) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(23)
            ["name"]=>
            string(14) "40''40FS4610R"
        },

    }
}
```

and need to send this array to view like json_encode() but getting error like: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

and when looking to error place it looks like this [image]

my php code looks like this:

```
$phone_models = Phone_model::get() -> all();

$models = array();
foreach($phone_models as $model){
    $models[$model -> manufacturer_id][] = array(
        'id' => $model -> id,
        'name' => $model -> name,
    );
}

$models = json_encode($models);
```

And JS code:

```
var models = $.parseJSON('{!!$models!!}');
```

Comment: There's no need to do that. Just echo the JSON directly into the JavaScript code; valid JSON is valid JavaScript (though the converse is not always true).

Comment: For what are the `!!` in the `$.parseJSON` part?

Comment: idk saw like this in blade templates and use'd.. because simple was not working ..

and if adding just php code

getting error like this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`

Comment: and between two single quotes getting large space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

`var models = <?php echo $models?>;`

there is no need to parse the json if it is part of the html output/content.

`echo "var xyz = ".json_encode([1,2,3]).";";`

becomes

`var xyz = [1,2,3];`

Comment: still it returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string` because in my model name there is double single quotes `''` not double quotes `"` but 2x of single ` ' and ' ` without any space

Comment: OMG SORRY.. i just needed to remove my quotes from JS variable.. SORRY it is working..!!!! YEAH!! :))

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you can place the array inside JavaScript using `json_encode()` (see [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

Simply use something like the following PHP:

```
<?php
$array = ('foo', 'bar', array('foo', 'bar'))
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>

</script>
```

This prints the array into a script element.

Answer (score 1):

complementing @JustOneUnderMillions and @RemcovanOs answers, I made this PHPFiddle that shows an working example:

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/sm1x-zu6d

Code:

```
<script>
    var json = 
<?php
class Model {
    function __construct($mi, $id, $name) {
        $this->manufacturer_id = $mi;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;    
    }
    public $manufacturer_id;
    public $id;
    public $name;
}

$pmodels = array(new Model(39, 21, "32''LE32HDF3010"), new Model(39, 22, "40''LE40FHDE3010"), new Model(39, 21, "40''40FS4610R"));
$models = array();

foreach($pmodels as $model){
    $models[$model -> manufacturer_id][] = array(
        'id' => $model -> id,
        'name' => $model -> name,
    );
}

$models = json_encode($models);


echo $models;        
?>;
    console.log(json);
</script>
```

Comment: your code helped me to understand what was suggested by @JustOnUnderMillions